# EF4: Object Context consuming too much memory

Tags: entity-framework, memory, garbage-collection

I have a reporting tool that runs against an MS SQL Server using EF4. The general bulk of this report involves looping over around 5000 rows and then pulling numerous other rows for each one of these.
I pull the initial rows through one data context. The code that pulls the related rows involves using another data context, wrapped in a using statement. It would appear though that the memory consumed by the second data context is never freed and usage shoots up to 1.5GB before an out of memory exception is thrown.

Here a snippet of the code so you can get the idea:

```
var outlets = (from o in db.tblOutlets
                       where o.OutletType == 3
                       && o.tblCalls.Count() > number && o.BelongsToUser.HasValue  && o.tblUser.Active == true
                       select new { outlet = o, callcount = o.tblCalls.Count() }).OrderByDescending(p => p.callcount);

        var outletcount = outlets.Count();
        //var outletcount = 0;
        //var average = outlets.Average(p => p.callcount);


        foreach (var outlet in outlets)
        {
            using (relenster_v2Entities db_2 = new relenster_v2Entities())
            {
                //loop over calls and add history
                //check the last time the history table was added to for this call
                var lastEntry = (from h in db_2.tblOutletDistributionHistories
                                 where h.OutletID == outlet.outlet.OutletID
                                 orderby h.VisitDate descending
                                 select h).FirstOrDefault();
                DateTime? beginLooking = null;
```

I had hoped that by using a second data context that memory could be released after each iteration. It would appear it is not (or the GC is not running in time)

Comment: what else is happening in the `foreach`?

Comment: there is some code which pulls child rows for the outlet and performs a few calculations. there are a rather large set of these rows however. The end result is a set of new objects that are adding to the outer data context to be saved to the database

Comment: I suspect that adding to the outer context is what is causing the problem.  If you comment out just that code that adds to the outer data context, is your memory usage ok?  In general, I don't think you want to have a context open and holding a large number of changes to be committed all at once.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Ill give it a go and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

With the input from @adrift I altered the code so that the saving of the changes took place after each iteration of the loop, rather than all at the end. It would appear that there is a limit (in my case anyway) of around 150,000 pending writes that the data context can happily hold before consuming too much memory.

By allowing it to write changes after each iteration, it would appear that it could manage memory more effectively, although it did seem to use as much, it didn't throw an exception.